# Check current Item Id against remote validation MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a scenario where I do not want to allow duplicate entries to database, and for this purpose I use Remote Validation property.
Inside model

```
  [Remote("DepartmentNameExists", "Department", "Department Name is already taken.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Inside Controller

```
  public JsonResult DepartmentNameExists(string name)
    {
        var user = db.Departments.Where(x => x.Name == name.Trim());

        return !user.Any() ?
          Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
          Json(string.Format("{0} is allready exists.", name),
              JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

It works well for Create view but when go to Edit there is some issues, Like on Edit page submit click it will validate the name again and will prevent page from submitting as already there is same entry in database (which is my current active item itself). How can I solve this problem?
Note:I can't remove validation from edit page, as there is a chance of user entering any other existing name rather than current one.

Comment: One option is to use the `AdditionalFields` property to pass the value of the ID property. If it has a value (assuming `int?`) or > zero (assuming `int`) then its an existing object, so you make whatever other checks you need to validate.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you please add it as an answer with necessary code sample . So that I can make a try

Comment: Bit hard without knowing what the logic is. I assume you want to return false if there any matching names, except if its the same as the name for current item in the database (in which case you return true because its OK). If that's the case, I'll post an answer (but its late so it will have to wait until tomorrow)

Comment: Okay, It is correct logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `AdditionalFields` of `RemoteAttribute` and use the `Id` (Primary key) of that table.

```
[Remote("DepartmentNameExists", "Department", "Department Name is already taken.", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In the controller, check if the Name exists Except for the one you're editing currently.

```
public JsonResult DepartmentNameExists(string name, int id = 0)
{
    return db.Departments.Any(x => x.Name == name.Trim() && x.Id != id) 
              ? Json(string.Format("{0} already exists.", name), 
                                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
              : Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Why you initialised ID as zero??

Comment: It is not required. Just in case when you're "Creating", if the Id value is null instead of zero.